# Getting Text value of Textblock element

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-8

Textbox text value can easily return to a string value but I can not return a textblock element's text value.
For example: how can I get fxzz.Text?

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="aaa"  Margin="-20,-19,-18,157" LayoutMode="List"  Background="#FFF9F9F9" BorderBrush="#FFE6E6E6" Foreground="#FF171717" FontSize="20">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                <TextBlock  x:Name="fxzz"   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Text="{Binding name}" FontStyle="Normal" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" />
                <Button x:Name="btn_Parse2" Click="btn_Parse2_Click" Content="folow" Tag="{Binding name}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="150" Background="#FF0C43A2" Foreground="#FFE6E6E6" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Height="Auto" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="20"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

I want to return it with that code like:

```
textblock value --- button
textblock value --- button 
textblock value --- button 
textblock value --- button 
textblock value --- button 
textblock value --- button
```

when i click button i want to get the value for single item

Comment: your question is unclear.

Comment: where are you binding the value to the textblock? is not the same value you need

Comment: after binding , how can i pass values i cant find a way to pass after  btn_parse2  click.. so i want to pass values after long list selector lists. each of them has buttons to pass values.

Comment: Post the code where you bind the data

Comment: binding is not the issue, i can bind, but after binding i want to get these values seperately and submit the server again. think a list of username and follow buttons, i can pull the username information from server and then i have to pass these names to server again but at that point i cant get textblock Text property to get the values